# Bash not recognising strings as equal

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have two variables `line` and `sorted`, which are both space-delimited strings of numbers. Part of my script depends on checking whether these two strings are equal:

```
if [[ $sorted == $line ]]
then
echo "test"
fi
```

When running this I get no output. A visual check, using: `echo $sorted` and `echo $line` gives two seemingly similar outputs.

I thought that this may be due to either of the two outputs having an extra white space character at the end, so I decided to check whether removing spaces from the strings removed the problem:

```
test1=`echo $sorted | tr -d ' '`
test2=`echo $line | tr -d ' '`
```

Subsequently performing:

```
if [[ "$test1" == "$test2" ]]
then 
echo "test"
fi
```

Did give the desired "test" output. However, when comparing the number of characters of both variables using `wc`, the output is the same for both variables. Furthermore, checking the number of white space characters in `line` and `sorted` with `echo <variable> | grep -o "\s" | wc -l` *also* gives the same output for both variables.

My question is what could be causing this behaviour; running `tr` removes the problem, yet counting the number of white spaces with `wc` and `grep` shows that the number of spaces (or at least, characters) is similar.

Comment: Tried using $sorted -eq $line  ?

Comment: @doc `-eq` is used to compare integers, not strings.

Comment: Without quoting the variables your `grep`/`wc` count tests are almost certainly incorrect. Also `wc -l` counts lines and your `echo` output should only ever have one line (if you don't quote your variables and even if you do if the variable contents are space-delimited and not newline-delimited).

Comment: Actually, you should even double-quote the variables in `if [[ $sorted == $line ]]` -- without quotes, `$line` will be treated as a pattern (i.e. subject to wildcard matching) rather than a plain string. Try `[[ [a-z] == [a-z] ]] && echo match` and `[[ abcd == a* ]] && echo match` to see this effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that some of your tests to see whether the strings are the same are broken, because you're not quoting your variables. This test should show a different count for the two variables:

```
echo "$var_name" | grep -c "\s"
```

You can use `declare -p var_name` to see the contents of your variable, which should show you where the leading/trailing white space is.

As you're using bash, you can also take advantage of the `<<<` *here string* syntax instead of using `echo`:

```
grep -c "\s" <<<"$var_name"
```

As [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro) points out in the comments (thanks), this is a more robust approach and saves creating a subshell.

Comment: Rather than use `echo`, you might consider `grep -c "\s" <<< "$var_name"`. Not only does the pipe create a subshell, but the here string is immune to some formatting (e.g. leading dashes) that can break `echo`.

Comment: @kojiro edited, thanks. I was aware of `<<<` being a built-in but could you elaborate on the issues with `echo` and formatting?

Comment: `echo` supports some options: `-n`, `-e` and `-E`. So passing unsanitized arguments can cause unintended effects. Careful quoting can avoid some of these effects, but even so it's better to be aware of them. For example: `x=(-n hello world); echo "${x[@]}"`

Comment: ...bash's echo, specifically, supports those options; POSIX echo, on the other hand, *doesn't* support those options, and bash actually breaks the POSIX sh standard by including them. (This is part of why using `printf` in preference to `echo` is good practice in general).